# Как передать значение переменной в ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня есть переменная
`$b = 3; $c = 4;`
`$a = $b * $c;`
Как мне передать переменную $a в ajax для обработки? Я не как не пойму. Может дать кто то пример как передаются переменные в ajax. Не где найти не могу.

Comment: `echo $a` ?....

Comment: Это тут причем? как передаются переменные в ajax data: ?

Comment: а вот кликни мышкой на тег [tag:ajax]. Ни одного примера не найдешь?

Comment: Отправить или получить?

Comment: У меня есть `$sum += $value->cart_amount * $value->price` которая считает сумму товаров в корзине. При удаление товара аяксом, сумма остается старая до перезарузки. Я так понимаю, что эту переменную нужно как то передать в ajax data: обработать и вывести результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
...
$a = 'somedata';
echo json_encode(['a'=>$a]);

...
//js code
$.get('somescript.php', function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState != 4 || this.status != 200) {
        return;
    }
    var response = this.responseText; // <-- ОТВЕТ СЕРВЕРА
}
request.send();
```